# Application in linear differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Hey I'm a little stuck on where to proceed on this question:

The initial value problem:

$$x′(t) = ae^{−bt}x(t)$$ $$x(0) = x_0$$

arises from a model of tumor growth. The constants a and b are positive; the size of the tumor, x = x(t), is initially equal to $x_0$. Determine a formula for the solution x(t). What does the model predict will be the long-term fate of the tumor (i.e. its size in the limit as t gets large).

So far I predit that the timor size will decrease exponentially to 0, but how would i go about doing the equation?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You face a separable first order differentail equation since $$x′ = ae^{−bt}x$$ can rewrite $$\frac{dx}{dt}=ae^{−bt}x$$ that is to say $$\frac{x'}{x}dx=ae^{−bt}dt$$ Si, integrating both sides, you arrive to $$\log(x)=-\frac{a e^{-b t}}{b}+C$$ that is to say $$x=C e^{-\frac{a e^{-b t}}{b}}$$ and using the initial condition $$x=x_0 e^{\frac{a(1- e^{-b t})}{b}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x'}{x}=\frac{a}{e^{bt}} \iff \ln(x) =-\frac{a}{b e^{bt}}+c \iff x= e^{-\frac{a}{b e^{bt}}+c}=x_0 e^{{}^{-\frac{a}{b e^{bt}}}}$$

In case you're more interested, you can solve this DE as a linear one or multiply both sides by $e^{\frac{a}{b e^{bt}}}$ to make it an exact/total and solve it like one.